# Android layout_below in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-relativelayout

I came across a strange issue, below is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ImageView
    android:src="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:text="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

`TextView` is not below `ImageView` as expected, it's below the original position of `ImageView`.

If i set `layout_height` of `RelativeLayout` to `200dp` or `match_parent`, it works fine.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Well it's a relative layout. You need to specify where each element will be relative to another. To align all elements in a row or column use LinearLayout

Comment: why did you add first image view?If you want to change the background color of the layout there is another way.

Comment: Use match_parent instead of wrap_content to root layout.

Comment: Don't use separate imageview for "PINK" color, u can set color to relative layout using setBackground attribute. Also u r using android:layout_centerInParent="true" for second imageview.. so don't use that attribute if you want to set TextView below ImageView. Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for you is to use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your root layout.

If you are using `wrap_content` for your root layout, `android:layout_centerInParent` and `android:layout_below` will not work properly.

Either use height as `match_parent` or static.

**choice 1 :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp">
```

**choice 2 :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**choice 3:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now its upto you to use which solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Relative Layout` to `Wrap Content` and Your Second `Image view` Apply with `layout_centerInParent` then you need to give `marginTop` to `Text View`.

**Try with below code.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageTest"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is Screen Shot.**

[image]

Comment: Thank for help me.

Comment: @xujifa Please upvote and accept the answer if it is Helpful to you. thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Thank for everyone answered.
I have got a solution at last. It is not a very good solution, but it works fine.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:src="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="warp_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/background"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/background">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is actually not necessarily true. You do not need to give the element a margin top for it to be below the image view. In my situation, I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and a ListView. I wanted ImageView to be above ListView but the ListView to cover the area below the ImageView. And I achieved it by setting `layout_alignParentTop` to the ImageView and adding `layout_below` to the ListView.

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="io.menuloop.menuloopandroid.MainActivity">
    <ImageView android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/yourStory" android:src="@drawable/ic_face_black_24dp" />
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yourStory"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:id="@+id/listView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```